# When calling up a website in selenium, the page is not logged into my google account

Tags: selenium

When I get a website in selenium, for example, driver.get('www.website.com') the site comes up but google is not logged in to my account.

I need it to be logged into my google account in order to use a google extension.

Comment: Have you tried any code? Are you getting any errors when you try to login to google account

Comment: no by default browser will get launched without any profile, you will have to write code to logged in using Selenium